# Outlook Android no longer synchronizes Office 365 contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, outlook

As of version *2.2.74* my Android Outlook *does not sync any contacts*.

The previous version has synced all of my coworkers from Office 365, but after a factory reset my coworker contacts are missing.

There is a setting in the application that shows if I enable contact synchronization and it is set on.

In Accounts and synchronization settings, I have an Outlook type account, and it has the Sync contacts set on and the last sync took place seconds ago.

In the new version of Outlook Android, there is a new tab called Persons, and it says I have 0 contacts. I guess this new feature is not working as expected.

Do you have any idea why these settings can't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems, they restructured how the contacts are synchronized.

I checked my Outlook on my computer, and it has 2 *separate contact store options:*

> Address book - mycompanyemail@mycompany.com
>
> Contacts - mycompanyemail@mycompany.com

All my company coworkers were in the *Address book* and my *Contacts* were empty.

I copied them to *Contacts* and now they are all synchronized - even appear in the new Contacts tab of Outlook Android.

So to draw a lesson: always check your online *Contacts* and see what it contains.